# Adding 'Vol." before the volume number in a plainnat bibliography

Tags: natbib

I'm working out how to edit a `.bst`-file to customise a bibliography. I have made a number of changes, but I am struggling to work out how to add "Vol." to the reference before my volume. As you can see, I have edited the standard `plainnat.bst` below to as `'no.'` before number and `'p.'` before page, but this was just through trial and error and a good guess based on what was showing.

```
 FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
     'skip$
    { "\penalty0 \ no. " number * "," * *
       volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
   if$
   pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
       { "\penalty0 \ p. " * pages n.dashify * }
     if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Please can someone advice on what changes to make to add `"vol."` before my volume number.

Comment: Maybe not applicable, but I find it a lot easier to customize biblatex macros than BibTeX styles. So you could consider switching to biblatex if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. For next time, I may consider learning that. However I am 48hrs off of my deadline and this is the last problem with my plainnat file, so I am going to just get this done this way!

Comment: I can't test it and am not so firm in `.bst` language, but does `"Vol.~" volume field.or.null *` or `"Vol.~" * volume field.or.null` help?

Comment: Thanks moewe, that worked for me. If you make that an answer I will mark it as having worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naive method

```
"Vol.~" volume field.or.null *
```

seems to work. This does no checking as to whether the volume field is empty or not.

If you want checking, try

```
volume empty$
  { "" }
  { "Vol.~" volume field.or.null * }
if$
```

Comment: It works, although I am now finding the problem of one reference having no value in Vol, but as this is online only I will switch the reference type to a URL

Comment: @MatthewRickard Mhh, yes I couldn't get a check for the empty field to work that quickly, but check the update it should work now. Normally it is very safe to assume that an `@article` does have a `volume` field. If your `@article` doesn't have a `volume` chances are very high it isn't actually an `@article`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not currently have a computer with LaTeX available, but as you are in a hurry, I'll give it a shot, hoping I remember the fairly arcane `.bst`-syntax well enough. I think this should do the trick for you:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  volume empty$
    'skip$
    { "Vol. " *  }
  if$number empty$
     'skip$
    { "\penalty0 \ no. " number * "," * *
       volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
   if$
pages empty$
 'skip$
 { duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ format.pages }
    { "\penalty0 \ p. " * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Let me know how far you get with this. I can check back here on my phone or tablet, and I should be back at my computer in a few hours.

Comment: I am afraid this hasn't worked. Now I get the errors when compiling the bibtex:

    ---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Vidal-Madjar:2003aa
while executing---line 1438 of file plainnat.bst
    `'105' is a function literal, not a string or missing field, for entry 1538-4357-604-1-L69
    while executing---line 1438 of file plainnat.bst
    `skip$' is a function literal, not a string, for entry 1538-4357-604-1-L69
    while executing---line 1438 of file plainnat.bst

Comment: User Moewe gave a suggestion that worked, but gave it as a comment so I can't mark it as an answer that worked for me.